# As a client, how do I know that a transaction I pushed is irreversibly confirmed?

Tags: transactions, irreversible

I push a transaction to a node and receive a transaction id in return. How do I know that transaction is irreversibly confirmed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/395/is-there-any-method-to-know-whether-a-transaction-has-been-confirmed-or-not

Comment: Not a duplicate. There is a difference between "confirmed" (the other question) and "irreversibly confirmed" (this question). See: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Glossary at "Block".

Comment: I've looked at the glossary definition you've pointed out, as well as the other question. Still, you either have a block id containing your transaction (processed), or you don't (not processed). Moreover, that block is either irreversible, or it's not far back enough (falling before the `last_irreversible_block`).

Answer (score 1):

From the wiki: https://github.com/EOSIO/eos/wiki/Smart-Contract#transaction-confirmation

> On completion of the transaction, a transaction receipt is generated. Receiving a transaction hash does not mean that the transaction has been confirmed, it only means that the node accepted it without error, which also means that there is a high probability other producers will accept it.
>
> By means of confirmation, you should see the transaction in the transaction history with the block number of which it is included.

You can pull a transaction by its id, and check if it has a `block_num`

Where a transaction looks like

```
{
  "expiration": "2018-04-01T15:20:44",
  "region": 0,
  "ref_block_num": 42580,
  "ref_block_prefix": 3987474256,
  ...
}
```

Note: I haven't actually tried this myself

Comment: This seems to indicate that the transaction has been included in a block, which does not necessarily indicate finality AFAIK. How is finality assured?

Comment: Do you mean "irreversibility"? See https://eosio.stackexchange.com/questions/395/is-there-any-method-to-know-whether-a-transaction-has-been-confirmed-or-not

Comment: Yes indeed I do.