# Transaction executed, but not confirmed?

Tags: cleos, nodeos, transactions

I need to know, if my transaction has been confirmed by the network.

My workflow to do this is the following:

1. Execute a transaction
2. By running cleos get transaction ID obtain the information
3. According to [this](https://eosio.stackexchange.com/a/396/2336), determine if if "block_num" < "last_irreversible_block", and conclude if the transaction has been confirmed or not.

I am running a single node EOS blockchain locally.

```
nodeos -e -p eosio --plugin eosio::chain_api_plugin --plugin eosio::history_api_plugin --contracts-console
```

After creating an account and pushing an action I want to obtain some information about the executed transaction, which should update some data on the ledger.

I executed the following:

```
cleos push action anorak update '["anorak",1,7,10]' -p anorak@active
executed transaction: 01b56d215ddeec880a9dbbd1a0660477a1069e93d7b6b74b63900c889f71f916  128 bytes  364 us
#        anorak <= anorak::update               {"account":"anorak","level":1,"healthPoints":7,"energyPoints":10}
warning: transaction executed locally, but may not be confirmed by the network yet    ]
```

I see that the transaction should be part of the created block by this:

```
2018-09-28T13:24:45.501 thread-0 producer_plugin.cpp:1419 produce_block ] Produced block 000000c33e4c8aa5... #195 @ 2018-09-28T13:24:45.500 signed by eosio [trxs: 1, lib: 194, confirmed: 0]
```

But I don't see the confirmed: 1 in the logs later and when I execute:

```
cleos get transaction 01b56d215ddeec880a9dbbd1a0660477a1069e93d7b6b74b63900c889f71f916
```

I still got: **Error 3040011: The transaction can not be found**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright I was able to obtain the transaction, when I added the block number option

```
cleos get transaction 01b56d215ddeec880a9dbbd1a0660477a1069e93d7b6b74b63900c889f71f916 -b {block_num}
```